# Send proactive message for Skype using Direct Line API

Tags: c#, botframework, skype, direct-line-botframework

I am using Direct Line API v4 to send a message to my Web Chat proactively using an existing conversation (by passing the existing conversation ID, saved when the conversation started).

Code:

```
var client = new DirectLineClient("secreat");
var activity = new Activity();

activity.From = new ChannelAccount("userid");
activity.Type = "resume";
activity.ChannelId = "directline";
activity.Text = "Hi";
activity.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "existingconverstaionid");
var result = client.Conversations.PostActivity("existingconverstaionid", activity);
```

This code runs fine and I am able to continue with my existing conversation with my Web Chat channel. I would like this same functionality to work for my Skype channel, so I have replaced `userid` and `existingconversationid` I received from the Skype conversation, but this does not work...

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to do? Please understand that Direct Line is used for client applications to communicate with a bot. It is its own channel. If you're using Direct Line then you don't need Skype. Skype and Direct Line don't communicate with each other. When we talk about proactive messages, that usually refers to bots. So are you trying to make a bot or a client application or what?

Comment: When you say you want to use Direct Line to communicate with Skype, do you perhaps mean you want to use the REST API to communicate with Skype?

Comment: We are using two channels for bot skype and directline,We have situation where user can ask for help using help command with his query, then latter we want to send response to user query., we can do this using connector client to send message to skype...
But i want this conversation happen through bot pipeline as we are maintaining user specific information in botstate on persistant store.
For ex. u can send some fake activity to bot using directline and then you can identify where user left and continue your logic,
I would like to send same fake activity to bot from skype

Comment: I don't know how to explain this,but i hope this explains what we are trying to do. please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Or i can say we want to send procative message for skype channel from the bot.

Comment: So you are writing bot code and not client code, correct? If that's the case, why are you using DirectLineClient?

Comment: I'd like to clarify something. When you say "We have situation where user can ask for help," do you mean help from a human? Are you perhaps talking about [bot-to-human handoffs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the DirectLineClient to broadcast a message to the Skype channel. It is actually quite easy, since you can just use the BotFramework SDK to send a proactive message, as long as you saved the conversation info.

Read more about sending proactive messages using [BotFramework v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) or have a look at the [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages).